# T/F: If the sequence $(a_{n})_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converges and the sequence $(b_{n})_{n=1}^{\infty}$ does not converge, then ...

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

T/F: If the sequence $(a_{n})_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converges and the sequence $(b_{n})_{n=1}^{\infty}$ does not converge, then the sequence $(a_{n} + b_{n})_{n=1}^{\infty}$ does not converge.

I thought about finding some $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ that contradict this but I can't think of any (because it's a sum and not multiply).

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $(a_n)$ converges and $(b_n)$ does not. Note that if $(a_n)$ and $(c_n)$ converges, then so does $(a_n)+(c_n)$. Thus, if $(a_n)+(b_n)$ would converge, then so would $(a_n+b_n)-(a_n)=(b_n)$.